# Are two forces required to cause shearing?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, hydraulics

If we have a fluid, is one force acting along the surface of it enough to cause sheering? In most diagrams I see for real Newtonian fluids they show two forces of equal magnitude along the top and bottom, but most problems I have done involve a single force acting over a real fluid, such as a block acting on a liquid.Is the deformation requiring two opposite forces?

Comment: Aren't there always two forces? "for every force there is always an equal and opposite force"...

Comment: @SolarMike And inertia produces the opposite force in an object when there is no second obvious force.

Comment: @DKNguyen but do you think the OP understands?

Answer (score 1):

A single force on a material is sufficient to cause shearing; the material will begin to translate and (if the force isn't applied to the center of mass) rotate, and a shear stress state will arise internally because of the material's inertia.

In the context of standard elasticity, where the material is assumed to remain motionless, fully four forces are required: As noted above, one would cause translational acceleration, and adding an equal and opposite force (to produce a [couple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couple_(mechanics))) would cause rotational acceleration.

[image]  

[image]

Although we often see only two force arrows in schematics of sheared solids, this is because the orthogonal stabilizing forces are ignored (e.g., if the material has a large lateral extent, only small stabilizing forces building up at the ends are required to produce a sufficient offsetting moment), not because they don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Shear can occur thru two opposite forces, or a single force on the medium that lay against another medium/solid. The result of the latter is represented by a force and a reaction (due to shear friction) in the opposite direction.

Comment: That would make sense, because in the block example, indeed there is a small motion in the fluid against a ramp.

Comment: A fluid forced through the pipe is another example.

Comment: Not even another medium/solid is required. I can shear a material exposed to vacuum simply by lateral movement of its underlying support.